# Sending command line arguments with ZMQ and Python

Tags: python-3.x, zeromq

I am beginner in Python, ZMQ,networking or even coding in general, so please pardon my mistakes.

I am trying to send instructions to open notepad.exe from my desktop to my laptop like this:

**MAIN SERVER**

```
import zmq
import subprocess

try:
    raw_input

except NameError:
    raw_input = input #for python 3


#This will handle all the sockets we will open on the mainServer
context = zmq.Context()


#Socket 1 - Using for instructions
instructions = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
instructions.bind("tcp://*:5555")


#Socket 2 - Using for end of finished instructions
#doneWork = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
#instructions.bind("tcp://*:5556")



#Now we will press enter when the workers are ready

print("Press Enter when you want to send the instructions. Make sure test devices are ready")
_=raw_input()

print ("Sending tasks to test device. . .")



instruction_One= "subprocess.call(['C:\notepad.exe'])"

instructions.send_string('%s' %instruction_One)
```

and

**CLIENT**

```
import zmq
import sys

context = zmq.Context()

instructions = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
instructions.connect("tcp://192.168.0.12:5555")


while True:
  instruction_One=instructions.recv()
  string_of_instruction = instruction_One.decode("utf-8")
  sys.std.out.write(string_of_instruction)
  sys.std.out.flush()
```

I am sending the instructions in terms of string which encoded into binary through the socket. But on the client side (laptop), whatever I am fetching cannot be executed through command line. What is the stupid mistake I am making?

Comment: a quick edit on client code, it should be C:\\notepad.lnk

However I still get an error at subprocess.call(string_of_instruction)

Comment: `sys.std.out` -> `sys.stdout`

Comment: @falsetru oops thanks! Although that still gave me an error. I am still not sure how to run notepad.lnk after sending instruction through socket

Answer (score 1):

I found out the fix.

instead of `sys`, I have used `subprocess`.

```
subprocess(command, shell=True)
```

Thanks

Comment: `subprocess.call(...)` ?

Comment: my mistake yes subprocess.call(..) although I am finding myself with a problem.

Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.